# How do I start DNS console?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012

According to a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/niran_belliappa/archive/2014/01/16/step-by-step-configuring-crm-2013-internet-facing-deployment-ifd.aspx) (it says: "*Open DNS Manager by clicking Start, pointing to Administrative Tools, and then clicking DNS*") I'm trying to follow there should be some DNS thingy to pick. However, as the pictured below, there's no such think.

[image]

What do I miss?

Also, when googling for help, I saw in [another post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91b64116-ec1a-4f5d-9e78-46c03d9dfae1/cant-find-dns-manager) that I can execute *dnsmgmt.msc*. However, that doesn't execute anything when run from start menu on my machine - no error message, no nothing! When I execute it from *Windows/System32* I get the error that such command doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DNS server` is not installed on `Windows Server 2012` by default. It must be added as a server role.

Usage of the `Server Manager` is introduced [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/11/04/introducing-server-manager-in-windows-server-2012.aspx).